# Replace in SQL query from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to replace the subtable in a query from another table values.

I have got these two tables "DATA" :
[image]

and the second table which I would like to relace with the Pointer is "vwPointer"

[image]

I would like to paste the value of "vwPointer - PointerName - Produced" into the first Table "DATA - Pointer01"

I used this expression here:

```
Sum(case when Pointer01 then vw.PointerName = 'Produced' then vw.DisplayUnits end) AS SystemPointer,
```

This gives me an error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'.

How can I replace the first table with the second?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what is the **exact** error you get?

Comment: query runs on SQL Server

Comment: SQL Server has no `boolean` data type, so `when Pointer01` needs to be something like `when Pointer01 = 0`